# Any good source, book, ebook on learning/practicing bass fills?

Tags: bass-guitar

Hey Bass players and/or musicians,

I am reallly in need of improving my bass fill playing, so I am in need of all sorts of suggestions where to gain knowledge and more practice from? Any website, books, ebooks, etc is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, we don't like to discuss product recommendations on this site. You could look on Amazon or some other book reseller's site for reviews and possibly sample pages. And one tried and true way to improve playing is to learn to play what the greats played.

Comment: What do you mean by "fill", (1) fast riffs and licks or (2) building up walking bass lines.  But as Todd says product recommendations are not what the group is about.

Comment: 'Bass players **and/or** musicians'? Sounds like you're lumping us alongside drummers!!